# zoo error - $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, zoo

I've created a zoo object in order to apply the HargreavesSamani ET (Evapotranspiration) function from [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Evapotranspiration/Evapotranspiration.pdf) package.

The input data file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhbznsn37lgoots/OakParkR.csv?dl=0) and the code I've used is below with notes.

```
require(Evapotranspiration)
require(zoo)

data("constants")
OakPark<- read.csv("OakParkR.csv", header=TRUE)

#Fill the blanks in the csv with NAs
na.fill(OakPark,NA)

#convert to a zoo
OakPark <- as.zoo(OakPark)

#create a zoo series with the required variables
PE.data <- OakPark[ ,c(3,5)]

#Defining the function and associating the data with the function class
funname <- "HargreavesSamani"
class(PE.data) <- funname
```

Then when applying the function:

```
results <- ET(PE.data,constants)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in data$Tmax : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I've tried converting the large zoo to a data frame and trying again but the ET function only works on a zoo series, so this didn't work either.

Other help pages for '$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors' seem to suggest changing the format of the data, but I need to find a way around this without doing that.